# Are there any ways to install Awesome 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, window-manager, awesome

I'm doing to migrate from DE to WM, and like Awesome.

But at home I use Ubuntu 13.04 and can install the newest Awesome. At work I use Ubuntu 12.04 and it is older then Awesome, so how can I install the newest Awesome and all it dependencies on Ubuntu 12.04?